# Storing script names in a variable

Tags: unity-game-engine

new to unity so please ignore if I sound stupid.

I have to scripts references in a script. Example, script A and B are referenced in script C.

I need to store script A and B variable names in a another variable so that I can use that variable in conditioning.

```
private FemalePlayerAnimations femalePlayerAnimations;
private MalePlayerAnimations malePlayerAnimations;
private Variable variable; // Got Problem Here

void Awake()
{
    femalePlayerAnimations = GetComponent<FemalePlayerAnimations>();
    malePlayerAnimations = GetComponent<MalePlayerAnimations>();
}

void Start()
{
    if(1 + 1 = 2) // Some Condition
     {
        variable = femalePlayerAnimations;
     }
    else if(1 + 2 = 3) // Some Another Condition
     {
        variable = malePlayerAnimation;
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into interfaces. Have say iplayeranimation. Then have classes that implement that male and female then your variable is type iplayeranimation and can be either male or female

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll need to use inheritence and have your male/female animations inherit from the same base class.

i.e.

```
public abstract class BasePlayerAnimator : MonoBehavior {}

public class MalePlayerAnimator : BasePlayerAnimator {}

public class FemalePlayerAnimator : BasePlayerAnimator {}
```

Real question though is why do you need two different classes for male/female animations? wouldn't a single class with 2 different instances cover your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you don't simply want the name of the variable as a string.

The logic you are trying to implement here won't work. You can't have a variable that holds the `FemalePlayerAnimations` class hold a `MalePlayerAnimations` class.

You should reconsider the design of your program as you can have two different instances (prefabs) of the same theoratical `PlayerAnimations` class. This is how **Animation Controllers** work in Unity.

Alternatively you could use a boolean field to store states, for example: `bool useFemaleAnimations` that is changed in the conditions and implement the correct "script" where applicable.